# Hover Annotations in Pyplot line graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need help writing a code that will display data when someones mouse hovers over my graph.  Ideally they would hover over anywhere on the x-axis and it would display all three values for the y-axis.  I'll include a picture of my current chart.  I know this is a big ask for help, I'm just totally stuck.[image]

I currently have this really simply graph.

```
plt.title('Poverty Rate and Spending on Cash Transfer Programs')
plt.xlabel('Spending in Billions')
plt.ylabel("Poverty Rate")


plt.plot( 'spending_in_billions', 'child_allowance', data=table_poverty_rate, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=4, color='blue', linewidth=2)
plt.plot( 'spending_in_billions', 'adult_ubi', data=table_poverty_rate, marker='o', color='red', markersize=4, markerfacecolor='red', linewidth=2)
plt.plot( 'spending_in_billions', 'all_ubi', data=table_poverty_rate, marker='o', color='olive', linewidth=2,  markersize=4, markerfacecolor='olive')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Use plotly library or Bokeh for interactive graphs! Matplotlib does not have the options yet.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Is one better than the other for a hover function?

Comment: Plotly is the way to go. It is opensource now.  https://plotly.com/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/#plotting-inline

Answer (score 0):

Install plotly using Pip install. Here is a simple plot:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=x**2))
fig.show()
```